# effectively applying nil check in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, rescue

I have this code

```
args = x.lead_details.last.leads.last.country_id rescue nil
Function(args)
```

I have used rescue keyword to make sure I don't get errors like

```
 undefined method `country_id' for nil:NilClass,
 undefined method `leads' for nil:NilClass
```

Is there any better way I can achieve this?

Other approach is

```
Function(x.lead_details.last.leads.last.country_id if x.present? && x.lead_details.present? && x.lead_details.last? && so on)
```

Comment: Just being curious: What does `Function` do (I don't find it in the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/)), and according to what syntax rule can a `rescue` be passed as part of an expression? Could I then use an `ensure` as well at this place?

Comment: "Function" is the name of a random function.

Comment: But how do you manage having a `rescue` in the parameter list? When I try this, I get a syntax error.

Comment: @user1934428 this is most likely psuedocode - you can't use rescue in a parameters list and "inline rescue" - eg `foo(bar) rescue SomeError` should not be used. https://thoughtbot.com/blog/don-t-inline-rescue-in-ruby

Comment: @max : Highly interesting .... pseudocode resulting in real Ruby error messages. code0079: If you want discuss a concrete problem, please also post your concrete code, instead of inventing your own syntax.

Comment: @user1934428 It was self explanatory.

Comment: @max please remove the downvote.

Comment: @code0079 I haven't downvoted the question. Maybe focus a bit more on the quality of your questions so they don't get downvoted? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rescue nil` is evil. It does not just rescue nil errors. It eats everything you throw at it. For example:

```
class Foo
  def bar
  end

  def woo
    raise ArgumentError
  end
end

Foo.new.baz rescue nil # nil!
Foo.new.woo rescue nil # nil!
```

This applies to any [inline rescue](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/don-t-inline-rescue-in-ruby).

Ruby 2.3.0 introduced the safe navigation operator that lets you do:

```
x&.lead_details&.last&.leads&.last&.country_id
```

ActiveSupport also has a Object#try! method that can be used in older versions of Ruby:

```
x.try!(:lead_details).try!(:last).try!(:leads).try!(:last).try!(:country_id)
```

But you're really just pissing on the Law of Demeter here and you should refactor the code so you don't have to traverse down that insane method chain as you're really just burying tons of potential bugs and making debugging impossible.

See:

- [5 reasons not to use safe navigation operators](https://www.theguild.nl/5-reasons-not-to-use-safe-navigation-operators/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [safe navigation operator](https://rubyinrails.com/2017/11/17/safe-navigation-operator-ampersand-dot-in-ruby/) (`&.`) that was introduced in Ruby 2.3:

```
Function(x&.lead_details&.last&.leads&.last&.country_id)
```

It returns `nil` when you try to call a method on `nil`.